# Subtract two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following MS Access table:

```
itemid   qty  flag
1         2    0
1         1    1 
2         5    0
2         4    1
```

I want to write a query to get the balance (`qty-qty`) and group by `flag`.

As an example:

```
(sum of qty where flag =0) - (sum of qty where flag =1)
```

My final output should be:

```
1=1 
2=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT itemid,
       NZ(SUM(IIF(flag = 0, qty, 0)), 0) - NZ(SUM(IIF(flag = 1, qty, 0)), 0) AS difference
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY itemid
```

Comment: thank for your help difference come nicely  when itemid had flag 1 and 0 .but if itemid had flag only 0 then difference come as minus value

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where the difference might be negative?  Do you want to show zero in this case?

Comment: no if difference will negative it should be negative .but if 1- null =1

Comment: Wrap the `SUM()` calls in `NZ()`, and use zero in case a given flag (0 or 1) does not occur even once.

Comment: soo sorry for my mistake i was run your query change 1 and 0